# Пытаюсь убрать дефолтные кнопки у тега video

Tags: javascript, html, css

пытаюсь убрать дефолтные кнопки у video тега, нашёл в интернете вот такой код

```
*::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    display: none!important;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

но этот код убирает кнопки у абсолютно всех video тегов на текущей странице, я пытаюсь задать конкретный селектор вместо * но это не работает, кто ни-будь сталкивался с таким? Очень нужна ваша помощь, буду рад если найду тут ответ)

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте задать атрибут `controls="false"` тегу `video`  Если это действительно видео, а не встраиваемый iframe с youtube или vimeo, то должно помочь

Comment: или вообще не писать controls

Comment: Да помогло спасибо большое)